# Cannot redeclare class Application

Tags: php, class, pdo

Here is the index file where i initiate Application class. When i run it i get Fatal error:Cannot redeclare class Application in C:\xampp\htdocs\blog_with_pdo\project\classes\application.php on line 4

```
    <?php 
        if(!class_exists('Application')) { 
        require_once'./classes/application.php'; 
        $obj_app=new Application(); 
        }
    ?>            


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="asset/front_end/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <script src="asset/front_end/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="asset/front_end/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <?php 
            include 'includes/header.php';
            ?>
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="container">

                        <?php
                           include_once 'includes/left_sidebar.php';
                        ?>

                        <div class="col-md-8"></div>

                        <?php
                        include 'includes/right_sidebar.php';
                        ?>

                    </div>    
                </div>
            </div> 
            <?php
            include 'includes/footer.php';
            ?>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the Application class

```
    <?php
         require_once  'db_connect.php';

         class Application {

         public $pdo;

        public function __construct() {
        $obj_db = new Db_connect();
        $this->pdo = $obj_db->pdo;
        }
        public function select_all_published_category() {
        try {
            $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_category WHERE publication_status='1' ";
            $result = $this->pdo->query($query);
            return $result;
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }

      }
    }
```

Here is left_sidebar.php where i want to use Application class object.

```
    <?php

$result=$obj_app->select_all_published_category();
?>

<div class="col-md-2" style="border-right: 1px solid #ffcc99; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
    <nav class="nav-sidebar">

        <ul class="nav tabs">
            <li class="sidebar-brand">
                <a href="#home"><span class="fa fa-home solo">বিষয়ভিত্তিক</span></a>
            </li>
            <?php 
            while ($row=$result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { ?>
            <li><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab"><?php $row['category_name']; ?></a></li>
            <?php } ?>

        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks like some cyclic requiring of the declaration...

Comment: Found it. I had a second declaration of application class in header.php which is also a child page of index page.